# Toggling padding causes unusal layout change

Tags: css

I'm currently working on a site http://www.lovepotatoes.ovh3.microserveltd.co.uk/ and this question is in relation to the recipe search block which has a drop-down and 3 text fields.

In Firefox it shows nicely, whereas in other browsers the second text input is positioned oddly. I notice that in Firebug if I toggle the padding on and off in the text  tag then Firefox exhibits this behavior too.

What do I need to do to fix this and get a smooth flowing layout with 2 rows? Any explanation in general to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this `style="clear:left;"` to the `div` with the **ingredients 2** input, it should work.

```
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-ingredients-value-1"
style="clear:left;">
 <input type="text" class="form-text" maxlength="128" size="60" value=""
name="field_ingredients_value_1" id="edit-field-ingredients-value-1"
title="Ingredients 2" style="color: rgb(170, 170, 170);">
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh I'd done that and later deleted it as it didn't work. Accidentally put it on the wrong div!